# Format date in current locale until month using momentjs

Tags: javascript, internationalization, momentjs

Moment.js has a handy formats (`l`, `L`, `ll`, `LL`, `lll`, `LLL`, `llll` and `LLLL`) for formatting a date in the current locale.

The problem is that this formats date including the day. For example `moment('1986-02-05').format('LL')` will be output as `February 5, 1986`.

The reason why this doesn't work for me is that I only want to display the day, only the month. In English that would be `February 1896`.

Is there a way of formatting only month and year according to a locale? If not with momentjs, with any other library. I'd also take a link to a list of the strings that I could pass to `.format` for common locales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See momentjs [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) docs for a list of tokens that you can use to show date and time.

In your case, the relevant tokens are `MMM` for month name and `YYYY` for the year. Don't forget to load each locale you need to use, as described [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/loading-into-browser/).

You can use [`locale()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-locale/) function to change the locale of the given moment instance and [`moment.locale`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/) if you need you can [change locale globally](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/).

---

**EDIT:**

There is no built-in method to get the localized input you are looking for, but you can use moment [`localeData`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/) and `longDateFormat` to get localized format for `LL` (*Month name, day of month, year*) and then manipulate to strip the day of month part. The following snippet work for many locale, but it doesn't show the expected output for each locale (some fails: `es`, `eu`, `lt`, ...).

My suggestion is to define a subset of supported locales and manually define format for edge cases.

```js
function getMonthYear(value){
  moment.locale(value);
  
  // Get locale data
  var localeData = moment.localeData();
  var format = localeData.longDateFormat('LL');
  
  // Manage custom cases
  if( value === 'br'){
    format = 'MMMM YYYY';
  }
  if( value === 'en-ca'){
    format = 'MMMM, YYYY';
  }
  // if( value === ...) possible other cases
  
  // Check locale format and strip day from the first part
  if( format.match(/^D/g) ){
    format = format.replace(/^D\./, '').replace(/^D/, '');
  }
  format = format.trim();

  return moment('1986-02-05').format(format);
}

['af' , 'ar-dz', 'ar-kw', 'ar-ly', 'ar-ma', 'ar-sa', 'ar-tn', 'ar', 'az', 'be', 'bg', 'bn', 'bo', 'br', 'bs', 'ca', 'cs', 'cv', 'cy', 'da', 'de-at', 'de-ch', 'de', 'dv', 'el', 'en-au', 'en-ca', 'en-gb', 'en-ie', 'en-nz', 'eo', 'es-do', 'es', 'et', 'eu', 'fa', 'fi', 'fo', 'fr-ca', 'fr-ch', 'fr', 'fy', 'gd', 'gl', 'gom-latn', 'he', 'hi', 'hr', 'hu', 'hy-am', 'id', 'is', 'it', 'ja', 'jv', 'ka', 'kk', 'km', 'kn', 'ko', 'ky', 'lb', 'lo', 'lt', 'lv', 'me', 'mi', 'mk', 'ml', 'mr', 'ms-my', 'ms', 'my', 'nb', 'ne', 'nl-be', 'nl', 'nn', 'pa-in', 'pl', 'pt-br', 'pt', 'ro', 'ru', 'sd', 'se', 'si', 'sk', 'sl', 'sq', 'sr-cyrl', 'sr', 'ss', 'sv', 'sw', 'ta', 'te', 'tet', 'th', 'tl-ph', 'tlh', 'tr', 'tzl', 'tzm-latn', 'tzm', 'uk', 'ur', 'uz-latn', 'uz', 'vi', 'x-pseudo', 'yo', 'zh-cn', 'zh-hk', 'zh-tw'].forEach(localeName => {
  console.log(
    localeName + ':',
    getMonthYear(localeName));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

You can find similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42437261/4131048) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44307140/4131048)

---

The following script creates and displays a Map with the number of occurences for each `LL` string. As you can see there are 68 occurences of `D MMMM YYYY` (targeted by the regex of the previous snippet) and few other formats covered by the previous *`getMonthYear`*. This may help you define a list of *unsupported* case and define a custom workaround

```js
let formatMap = new Map();

['af' , 'ar-dz', 'ar-kw', 'ar-ly', 'ar-ma', 'ar-sa', 'ar-tn', 'ar', 'az', 'be', 'bg', 'bn', 'bo', 'br', 'bs', 'ca', 'cs', 'cv', 'cy', 'da', 'de-at', 'de-ch', 'de', 'dv', 'el', 'en-au', 'en-ca', 'en-gb', 'en-ie', 'en-nz', 'eo', 'es-do', 'es', 'et', 'eu', 'fa', 'fi', 'fo', 'fr-ca', 'fr-ch', 'fr', 'fy', 'gd', 'gl', 'gom-latn', 'he', 'hi', 'hr', 'hu', 'hy-am', 'id', 'is', 'it', 'ja', 'jv', 'ka', 'kk', 'km', 'kn', 'ko', 'ky', 'lb', 'lo', 'lt', 'lv', 'me', 'mi', 'mk', 'ml', 'mr', 'ms-my', 'ms', 'my', 'nb', 'ne', 'nl-be', 'nl', 'nn', 'pa-in', 'pl', 'pt-br', 'pt', 'ro', 'ru', 'sd', 'se', 'si', 'sk', 'sl', 'sq', 'sr-cyrl', 'sr', 'ss', 'sv', 'sw', 'ta', 'te', 'tet', 'th', 'tl-ph', 'tlh', 'tr', 'tzl', 'tzm-latn', 'tzm', 'uk', 'ur', 'uz-latn', 'uz', 'vi', 'x-pseudo', 'yo', 'zh-cn', 'zh-hk', 'zh-tw'].forEach(localeName => {
  var format =  moment.localeData(localeName).longDateFormat('LL');
  
  if( formatMap.has(format) ){
    let val = formatMap.get(format);
    formatMap.set(format, val+1);
  } else {
    formatMap.set(format, 1);
  }
  
});

console.log(formatMap);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This will not work as you are enforcing a specific order (MMM YYYY) but different languages have different conventions for this. 
In English "February 2015" when translated to chinese should be `2015年2月`. As you see, the month-year order is inversed and that is why I just can't use a fixed M/Y format, it has to be per-locale.

Comment: @miguel.camba I've edited my answer to provide an updated solution that I think is closer to what you are asking.

Comment: I guess that it could work if I manually inspect all the languages and find the exceptions. I was hoping for an authoritative source for that, but it is indeed a last option.

Comment: @miguel.camba you are right, as I stated in the answer _There is no built-in method to get the localized input you are looking for_, I've added a map showing the number of occurences for each `LL` string in order to help you _manually inspect all the languages and find the exceptions_. At the beginning I posted my answer only because I misinterpreted your question, otherwise I would simply had posted the similar (linked) question in comments. I'm trying to provide all info and workarounds in order to help you.

Comment: With your script I've manually found the exceptions that are not MMM YYYY and hardcoded them into my core, so I guess I can consider it correct. They are just 8.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer bellow code for required format, it will work :

```
moment.locale('en');
var date = moment(new Date());
console.log(date.format('MMMM YYYY'));
```

Comment: You can check my working code here : http://jsfiddle.net/Avinash_Jagtap/029bxLma/35/

Comment: It will not work as in some languages the year must be displayed before the month.